# How to nest "except:" inside of "when:" in ci.yml file

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I want all jobs to be manual except when branch is specific. It seems like this type of logic is invalid in .yml, but is there a better way to do it that is valid?

I have tried:

```
.test: 
  tags: 
    - Jobtag
  stage: test
  when: manual  
      except:
        - brachname
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems it not possible to nest `except` under `when` section. Then you can create two similar jobs but one of them will run manualy for branches where it's required and another always runs for branches where it's not:

```
.test-manual: 
  tags: 
    - Jobtag
  stage: test
  when: manual  
  except:
    - brachname 

.test-auto: 
  tags: 
    - Jobtag
  stage: test
  when: always
  only:
    - brachname
```